# Activemodel date validation and assignment in forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date, activemodel

I am using activemodel(Not activerecord, and I have the following code:

```
class PaymentForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming 

  attr_accessor :agree_auto_renew, :card_owner, :address1, :address2, :address3, :address4, :postcode,
                :firstname, :surname, :dob, :email, :email_confirmation
  validates_presence_of :agree_auto_renew, :card_owner, :address1, :address2, :address3, :address4, :postcode
  validates_presence_of :firstname, :surname, :email, :email_confirmation, :if => :not_owner
  validates_date :dob, :if => :not_owner
  validates_confirmation_of  :email, :if => :not_owner

  private
  def initialize
    @errors = ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
  end

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def not_owner
    ! self.card_owner
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

But when I try to validate the form, I got the following rails error on dates:

```
undefined method `dob(3i)=' for #<PaymentForm:0x007fe0379c3668>
```

How can I make activemodel auto convert dob elements into the dob variable?

Comment: not sure to understand what's `dob` ?

Comment: how is this suppose to work ? `dob(3i)`

Comment: I've got the same question, in case you've found an answer.

Comment: No, I don't think I did find an answer, I turn to use the active-record instead.

Comment: @phil88530 Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Pull Request to Rails 4.2 for that. You can dig into in on https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8189/files.